# IOS purchases - validated receipt contains multiple purchases with missing no corresponding transaction on the payment queue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

During our purchase testing against sandbox we have a device that seems to have picked up a purchase within the grand unified receipt that fails to restore itself on the payment queue which given we can't see it on the queue we can't finish it, but they continue to appear within the apple receipt that we verify on our server indefinitely indicating a payment is due. How can we finishTransaction on a payment that is missing from the PaymentQueue and isn't restored via restoreCompletedTransactions process?

The app here is signed production distribution, testing with a sandbox user.

1) on app start we register with the payment queue:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

2) no transactions are report via

```
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

3) we submit a new purchase to the sandbox, which purchases ok

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]
```

which then pops back as the only transaction in

```
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

4) we retrieve the receipt for the payment and send this transaction to the server to be validated

we only support ios8:

```
NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL* appStoreReceiptURL = [mainBundle appStoreReceiptURL];
receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:appStoreReceiptURL];
```

now... when verifying the receipt on our server we see two purchases, although we have only requested a single purchase:

> AppleAppReceiptValidationResult(0,AppleAppPurchaseReceipt(com.myapp,0,0,1375340400000,1.19.0.7787,
>       AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt(1,premium_pack_5,1000000151522392,1000000151522392,1429191268000,2015-04-13 14:44:43 Etc/GMT), 
>       AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt(1,premium_pack_5,1000000152000706,1000000152000706,1429191268000,2015-04-16 13:34:28 Etc/GMT)))

[note that we have even managed to get two transactions for the same SKU, which I didn't think should be possible]

5) The ios client then finishes the new purchase transaction:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:toFinish];
```

So here we have a problem as we don't have a handle on the old transaction as it wasn't recovered from the SKPaymentQueue addTransactionObserver, so we can't seem to finish it.

Any ideas on how to complete this transaction when it doesn't appear in the PaymentQueue?

We have tried

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]
```

but this doesn't clear or report the transaction on the queue and it continues to remain within all future purchase receipts.

Comment: What purchase types are you talking about? For a purchase type such as a  non-renewing subscription, it will remain in the receipt (but don't know why it wouldn't show up in the restore).

Comment: its a Consumable purchase. At the minute I think its just some hiccup with the apple sandbox environment, the apple development tools seem like there's some room for improvement.

Comment: Consumable purchases will not restore using Apple restore. It is a property of that purchase type.

Comment: Did you ever fix your problem? I am desperately facing the same issue and would appreciate if you could post your solution.

Comment: we have same problem. post a solution please if you solve this. @nidhoeggr09

Comment: No we never got to the bottom of it. In the end we figured it was an isolated issue on the apple sandbox environment, we haven't seen the same on production purchases.